# Local notification trigger only last ten days based an expiry dates

Tags: swift

Last 10 days need to trigger the local notification based our expiry date. For example, the current date is today date(`10-08-2019`) and the expiry date is (`20-08-2019`) between the days need to trigger the local notification. For the testing purpose changed the device date within the range of device expiry date (Based on 10 days range between a start date and expiry date).But not able to get the local notification for last 10  days. Last 10 days need to trigger the local notification every day. I have used the code below but I'm not getting the result.

```
func deviceExpiryReminder(){
    let dateString = "2010-08-20 00:00:00"
    let formatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
    if date != nil && date! > Date() {
        let message = "Device Expire Reminder"
        let title1 = "Your device is expire in {2} days"
        let title2 = "Your device is due to expire"
        let identifier = "DeviceExpire"
        //trigger for every day from configured days before
        for i in (0..<10) {
            let preTitleMsg = title1.replacingOccurrences(of: "{2}", with: String(i))
            var title = preTitleMsg
            if i == 0 {
                title = title2 + "today"
            } else if i == 1 {
                title = title2 + "tomorrow"
            }
            let userInfo = ["reminderType": "Device Expire",
                            "title": title,
                            "message": message,
                            "identifier": identifier]
            let timeInterval = TimeInterval(-1 * i * 24 * 3600)
            let triggerDate: Date = date!.addingTimeInterval(timeInterval)
            if triggerDate > Date() {
                createReminder(title, message, triggerDate, false, NSCalendar.Unit.day, nil, userInfo, identifier + String(i))
            }
        }
    }
}


 func createReminder(_ title: String, _ message: String, _ triggerDate: Date?, _ canRepeat: Bool, _ repeatInterval: NSCalendar.Unit, _ triggerDateComponents: DateComponents?, _ userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]?, _ identifier: String) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.body = message
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        var trigger:UNNotificationTrigger?
        if triggerDateComponents != nil {
            trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDateComponents!, repeats: canRepeat)
        } else {
            trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: (triggerDate?.timeIntervalSinceNow)!, repeats: canRepeat)
        }
        let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            }else {
                print("Notification added")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add next day with current day and changed time zone as system zone identifier.

Try let me know :

```
func deviceExpiryReminder(){
        let dateString = "2019-08-30 00:00:00"
        let formatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
        if date != nil && date! > Date() {
            let message = "Device Expire Reminder"
            let title1 = "Your device is expire in {2} days"
            let title2 = "Your device is due to expire"
            let identifier = "DeviceExpire"
            //trigger for every day from configured days before
            let numberofDays = self.daysBetweenDates(startDate: Date(), endDate: date ?? Date())
            for i in (0...numberofDays) {
                let preTitleMsg = title1.replacingOccurrences(of: "{2}", with: String(numberofDays - i))
                var title = preTitleMsg
                if numberofDays == i {
                    title = title2 + " today"
                } else if numberofDays - 1 == i{
                    title = title2 + " tomorrow"
                }
                let userInfo = ["reminderType": "Device Expire",
                                "title": title,
                                "message": message,
                                "identifier": identifier]
                var calendar = Calendar.current
                calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: self.getCurrentTimeZone())!
                let currentDay  = Date()
                let nextDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: currentDay)
                if nextDate! >= Date() {
                    createReminder(title, message, nextDate, false, NSCalendar.Unit.day, nil, userInfo, identifier + String(i))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func getCurrentTimeZone() -> String{
        return String (TimeZone.current.identifier)
    }
    func createReminder(_ title: String, _ message: String, _ triggerDate: Date?, _ canRepeat: Bool, _ repeatInterval: NSCalendar.Unit, _ triggerDateComponents: DateComponents?, _ userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]?, _ identifier: String) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = title
            content.body = message
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            // *** create calendar object ***
            var calendar = Calendar.current
            calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: self.getCurrentTimeZone())!
            let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .hour, .year, .day], from: triggerDate!)
            print("trigger dates one by one : \(triggerDate!)")
           let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: canRepeat)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            center.add(request) { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error")
                }else {
                    print("Notification added")
                }
            }
        }
    }

func daysBetweenDates(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) -> Int {
        let daysBetween = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate, to: endDate)
        print(daysBetween.day!)
        return daysBetween.day!
    }
```